# XLActionController doesn't know any class for example TweetbotActionController

Tags: ios, swift

I want to open a Tweetbot Action Controller, which is presented as an example in [XLActionController](https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLActionController):

```swift
let actionController = TweetbotActionController()

        actionController.addAction(Action("View Details", style: .default, handler: { action in
            // do something useful
        }))
        actionController.addAction(Action("View Retweets", style: .default, handler: { action in
            // do something useful
        }))
        actionController.addAction(Action("View in Favstar", style: .default, handler: { action in
            // do something useful
        }))
        actionController.addAction(Action("Translate", style: .default, executeImmediatelyOnTouch: true, handler: { action in
            // do something useful
        }))

        actionController.addSection(Section())
        actionController.addAction(Action("Cancel", style: .cancel, handler:nil))

        present(actionController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I made an instance of `TweetbotActionController` but it prompts the following error:

```
Use of unresolved identifier 'TweetbotActionController'
```

Comment: Did you import the library?

Comment: yes i import XLActionController to my VC

i clen the build folder and close xcode but error still show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git), make sure you have Podfile like:

```rb
use_frameworks!

target '<Your App Target>' do
  pod 'XLActionController'
  pod 'XLActionController/Tweetbot'
end
```

in order to use the provided examples.